# How to maintain a history in Android across activity

Tags: android

Considering the following scenario. There's an Activity_1, which creates another Activity_2, in Activity_1, some data are produced which needs to be recorded, and Activity_2 starts another Activity_1.

a) Will Activity_1 be brought to the top of calling stack, or will there be another instance Activity_3 that's the same class with Activity_1?

b) How do I recover the data generated in Activity_1, and make the show in Acitivity_3(or Activity_1 if it's simply brought to top). i.e., maintain the historical data in Activity_1

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is what flags you are setting during the start of new activity or calling an old activity. Below link will answer your question.
[Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) and [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Would suggest to read the whole article and you will never have any problems.

Comment: Can I save composite data types with SharedPreference? The doc says it can save primitive key-value pair

Comment: How do I clear sharedpreference when my application closes, as opposed to an activity stops. I don't want sharedpreference data to stay across instance of application launch

Comment: You can always remove any saved data using the Editor of sharedpreference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Comment: Yes only primitive data type are supported. To support different data types you can use Intent / Bundles / Extras to transfer data across activites.

Comment: Thanks Prachur. But the problem is When to call them? in onDestroy? I wanted the recorded data gone by the time the app closes, not individual activity closes

Comment: Then the best solution is use of getIntent(). In second activity oncreate use getIntent to get a reference to last intent. Now use this Intent to start the third activity by changing intent.setClass(context, Third.class) and add any other extra you want to add. Now when you are in third activity you can access the extras added in first activity and as well as second activity.